# For a .Net project, what file extensions should I exclude from source control?

Tags: .net, svn, version-control, file-extension

Everytime I start a project I have to think carefully about which files to exclude from source control. Has someone made a list of the criteria so I can look it up from the beginning? I work on my own so I have not got round to it.
I appreciate that in the case of a DLL, you would want to include some and exclude others, so it is not just dependent on the file extension.
My projects are ASP.Net, although a general discussion of other templates would also be useful.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what source control software do you use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732813/best-practices-for-subversion-and-visual-studio-projects/1732852#1732852

Comment: I see the reference to the previous question covers what I am asking for. Thank you to Adrian Banks.

Comment: Odd, I always focus on "what do I need to include".  Very easy to check too.

Comment: Have you tried the VisualSVN or AnkhSVN Visual Studio addins?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What .net files should be excluded from source control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992532/what-net-files-should-be-excluded-from-source-control)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From http://blog.goneopen.com/2009/06/git-excludes-for-dotnet/:

```
.DS_Store
._*
TestResults
*Resharper*
**.ReSharper**
**\_ReSharper.**
*.bak
*.cache
*.resharperoptions
*.suo
*.user
*.vsprops
*/TestResults
*\bin*
*\obj*
_ReSharper.*
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), be sure to exclude `_Resharper*` folders

If you're using Subversion for source control then the [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) Visual Studio plug-in will manage excludes for you automatically.

Be sure to *include* any third-party dlls that your project references that won't be in the GAC of your build or deployment machines. Our practice is to have a `lib` folder that all such dlls live in, and we add references to them from that folder. This ensures that the `hintpath` property in the `csproj` file is correct (it stores a relative path to the referenced dll).

Comment: I like the tip about using the lib directory. I also appreciate the info about Subversion.

Answer (score 3):

Do not sourcecontrol `bin` and `obj` folders, as well as `*.suo` and `*.user` (if you're using Visual Studio) files.

If you feel uneasy about keeping third-party DLLs in source control, try [Componento](http://www.componento.net/), which, granted, does not yet have a sizable components database.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, only source control files which are required to build the application.

Comment: +1 because its a good rule - though I suspect the question is, in part, prompting to work out what these are!

Answer (score 1):

Generic ingores from a project folder:

```
*.Cache
*.user
bin
obj
```

And from the solution (a level up)

```
*.cache
_PublishedWebSites
*.suo
```

We've also got the following - which are instance specific config settings referenced out of generic configs (i.e. web.config for asp.net apps)

```
AppSettings.config
Provider.config
connections.config
```

There are .config.sample files that *are* version controlled.

You should probably set bin, obj, *.cache, *.user and *.suo as global in your subversion setup - but as this is (if memory serves) machine specific you're probably going to end up doing explicit ignores anyway