# Can I delete Packages folder inside VS project?

Tags: visual-studio

Simple question. Is it safe to delete the "Packages" folder inside a VS project? The folder is too big and if I need to send a project somewhere its would take a long time. Will VS re-download the packages after deletion or this will broke the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, this is not a problem. Of course, it depends on the question if the packages can be re-aquired.

For instance, when all packages were installed by the nuget package manager, and were not unlisted or such, it should be no problem.

**PS:**
I recommend you still try it out.

If you are using git, you can easily just try it out, and if it doesnt work, revert.

Comment: All my packages are downloaded by nuget package manager inside VS so it should not be a problem to delete it. Right?

Comment: Normally, its no problem. I cant try it out (im having .netcore projects), but yes, it should be no problem. I think that folder is only meant as local cache.

Comment: here check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110471/what-is-the-packages-directory-in-visual-studio-should-i-include-it-in-svn