# Which Project Files Should I Distribute With my Source Code?

Tags: visual-studio

I am releasing the source code to my project and just wanted to know which files I can leave out (if any) but still ensure that they can open the VS solution correctly and compile.

I think its just the `bin` and `obj` folders - are there any more files/folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what version of Visual Studio you are using, you may want to look at one of these questions:

- [Mercurial .hgignore for Visual Studio 2008 projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784/mercurial-hgignore-for-visual-studio-2008-projects)
- [Mercurial .hgignore for Visual Studio 2010 projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095696/mercurial-hgignore-for-visual-studio-2010-projects)

These list the files that should be ignored by Mercurial (a version control system). They should be identical to the files that you can omit when you distribute your source code.

As a side note, if you're going to be distributing your source code, you probably want it under version control anyway. [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) are two popular, modern, and well-supported version control systems. [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/) is a bit easier, but not as powerful or well-supported.

Comment: I use Git (.gitignore). Thanks - just what I was after.