# hgignore: need to ignore all but one .lib file

Tags: mercurial, glob, hgignore

For my class project my team is using hg to work together and I made the ignore file from the checked answer on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095696/mercurial-hgignore-for-visual-studio-2010-projects), with a few additions. There's a problem though. I have a .lib file necessary to making the code run and I want it kept in the repository.

Since that .hgignore is using glob I am too, so how would I allow the file comp345_dnd/RollPlay.lib (root folder contains comp345_dnd) to be in/watched while *.lib is ignored?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just manually do hg add on the specific file (without any wildcards) e.g.:

```
hg add /path/to/file
```

This overrides the .hgignore file and adds the file to the repository.

Comment: No - the .hgignore only operates when you're specifying directories or patterns.  If you tell mercurial to add a specific real file, it does it, and then continues to track it, regardless of .hgignore.

Answer (score 2):

to quote Matt Mackall [in an old post on the mercurial-devel list](http://www.selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2008-April/019026.html):  *Mercurial will add any -files- explicitly specified on the command line, regardless of the ignore rules.*