# hgignore for Orchard

Tags: mercurial, orchardcms

I am just testing Mercurial for the first time. Can someone tell me what to put into the .hgignore file? - maybe post a sample here?

Comment: Did you clone Orchard using Mercurial? From which URL?

Comment: No, I dowloaded sources and installed mercurial afterwards... I assume the other way would have created a .hgignore file which is suitable for Orchard/VS2010 ?

Answer (score 0):

The [hgignore man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) explains what to put in the .hgignore file.

Answer (score 0):

Orchard modules are just a .Net Project so any .Net/C# .hgignore will serve your purposes as well. I'm using one right now from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095696/mercurial-hgignore-for-visual-studio-2010-projects). Check which Visual Studio version you're using as there are others specifically for 2012 and 2013 as well.